# Unable to set mouse in vim under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, vim

For some reason, I am unable to perform the

```
:set mouse=a
```

command in vim. I have installed pretty much every vim related package from apt that seems applicable. Vim version is 7.3 (Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI). +X11 is included.

This is a new workstation, with a previously installed version of ubuntu (that I can't change, because this is a work computer). I've never had a problem with this in the past, and have other machines where this works fine, running 12.04, 12.10, and older versions of Ubuntu. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you issue that command? Do you get an error?

Comment: nope. no error. just doesn't do anything. can't move window borders, selection includes line numbers, etc.

Comment: Strange, I have one idea left: try to play with `set ttymouse=xterm2` (Must be one of: `xterm, xterm2, netterm, dec, jsbterm, pterm`)

Answer (score 2):

guntbert's advice solved the problem. All that was necessary was to issue this command:

```
:set ttymouse=xterm2
```

Comment: @RickGreen-Turbo When the "thanks" answer is posted by the OP *and it is responding to a comment*, the best thing to do is usually not to delete or flag it, but to edit it so it's an answer.